# How do I render a partial view based on the list item a user clicked on?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a HomePageViewModel that takes various models and shows a summary view on the home page.

I'd like to filter the Announcements model based on the result of a drop down list, which I'm rendering as an unordered list.  This is my first time using partial views or anything like that, and after some reading decided to do it a HTML.Action call which calls DisplayAnnouncements from the Announcement Controller.

However, I'm unsure how to pass the parameter of what is clicked in the list (the "#" in the example below), to my HTML.Action method.

This is HomePage view:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Legal</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Accounting</a></li>
</ul>
@Html.Action("DisplayAnnouncments", "Announcement", new { filter = "All" })
```

And this is my announcement controller:

```
    public ActionResult DisplayAnnouncments(string filter)
    {

        return PartialView("_Announcements", 
            (from a in db.Announcements
             where a.Type == filter
             select a).Take(4));
    }
```

My _Annoucments partial view:

```
<table class="table" style="table-layout: fixed">

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 70px">
            @item.AnnouncmentDate.ToShortDateString()
        </td>
        <td>
            <strong>@item.Title</strong><br />
            @item.Announcment
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

So to reiterate, I have a few questions:

1. How to I get the list item that the user clicked to populate the appropriate filter in my HTML.Action?
2. Is HTML.Action the best thing here?  Should I be using something else?
3. How do I only refresh the partial view so the whole page doesn't refresh?

Thanks for your help, I'm quite new to this!

Robbie

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way could be to use some javascript to copy the drop down selected value inside a hidden field of your partial view then simulate a click of one of your partial view (hidden) submit button.

partial view:

```
<table class="table" style="table-layout: fixed">

<input type="hidden" id="MyHiddenInput" name="selectedValue" />
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 70px">
            @item.AnnouncmentDate.ToShortDateString()
        </td>
        <td>
            <strong>@item.Title</strong><br />
            @item.Announcment
        </td>
    </tr>
}
<div style="display: none;"><input type="submit" id="myHiddenButton" /></div>
```

Parent view:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#" data-hval="all">All</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-hval="legal">Legal</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-hval="accounting">Accounting</a></li>
</ul>
```

and some jQuery:

```
$("dropdown-menu > LI > A").live("click", function() {
    $("#MyHiddenInput").val($(this).data("hval"));
    $("#myHiddenButton").click();
});
```

Comment: Hi Serge, apologies but I'm not sure I understand - I can add your javascript to my view, but not sure about how to then copy this into the partial view, nor how to simulate the submit button - also will this just refresh the partial view?

Comment: Thanks, much clearer - I've implemented it, but straight away when going to my page I get a javascript area (in the Chrome console) that Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined which points to this line:  $("dropdown-menu > LI > A").live("click", function() {

Comment: Do you set unobstrusive ajax? Because this should include jQuery on your pages.

Comment: No, it's not supported by Jquery 1.9.1 (which is what I'm using) http://forums.asp.net/t/1877166.aspx/1

Comment: Then don't use .live(...) but .bind(...) (or .click(...)).

Comment: Ok, I've put the JS into a document.ready function with some other code, and when I click on one of my list items the page scrolls to the top, but the filter doesn't change (this is either with .bind or .click)